# Vertical align ionic title on android

Tags: android, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app with the Ionic framework and cordova. I recently uploaded my app to test it out but noticed something. On android the title in the top bar is not aligned vertically. Is there any way to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably be a `line-height` issue. Try making the `line-height` of the element in which the text is contained in, or it's parent the same as the height of your top bar.

Try looking at the below classes and make sure the `line-height` and the `height` match up.

```
.bar .title
.bar
```

Comment: Okay, it did the trick on android but it messed up the title on the browser, so i used the .platform-android class to specify android only. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's android problem so I made style for android only. It worked for me!

`.platform-android .bar .title {
    line-height: 52px !important;
}`